# npm get-video-duration Error: Could not find ffprobe executable

Tags: node.js, express, npm

this package does'nt work and this error appear anyone know why

```
 Error: Could not find ffprobe executable, tried
 "C:\Users\amgad\Desktop\upload-videos\node_modules\@ffprobe-installer\win32-x64\ffprobe.exe"
 and "C:\Users\amgad\Desktop\upload-videos\node_modules\@ffprobe-installer\ffprobe\node_modules
\@ffprobe-installer\win32-x64\ffprobe.exe"
```